# Android build to share to other devices and to upload on itch.io

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, adb, game-engine

I am currently working on an android game but when I try to build it, we can do it in two ways i.e.

If we check the Bundle Opting in the build menu then it will come in a single file of formate .adb (Android Debug Bride) it may or may not work with Google Play Store or the App Store but I am not targeting on that I wanted a file or files that I can share with my friends or on itch.io because you can only upload a file or files on it, it is not responsible for installing for anything and whoever downloads the from it, he will just get the file on his/her android device and will not get an installed app to start playing it.

we can also check the Splitting opting in the player menu of project setting and then the build will split into two files, 1. .apk , 2. .obb. well this is a good option but with the same problem if I upload it to a distributor or share it to my friends the two files will be downloaded or shared with no installation

Please tell me a way how I can make a file that can download itself or any solution to this.

I just want a way to build an android game that can easily be installed through a distributor or through sharing

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Are you sure it's adb and not aab?

Comment: `Please tell me a way how I can make a file that can download itself` may not be the ideal approach for this site.  Typically one would make and attempt and then as for help should error messages arise,

Answer (score 1):

What you want is just an **APK**.

An app bundle is intended for the Google Play Store. If you upload your app as an app bundle to the Play Store, Google repackages it into multiple APKs which only contain the data and code that is required for specific device configurations of end users. E.g. it only contains specific languages, and code for specific architectures and so on.

If you enable the "Split Application Binary" option, Unity limits the size of your APK to 100MB since this is the limit of the Google Play Store. It then creates the [expansion file](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html) (`.obb`) which you would also upload to the Play Store.

In your case, you don't need any of it. You need one APK.

Disable "Build AppBundle (Google Play)" and "Split Application Binary" and you should be able to create one big APK.